# Follow HTTP 302 redirect in Apigee

Tags: apigee, http-status-code-302

I'm working on creating a proxy to an endpoint to which I have to POST form values. The server returns a 302 redirect to which I have to do a GET.
I am trying to do this using sequential callouts but it doesn't look very clean and the cookies don't seem to be passed through completely.
Is there an easier way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try leveraging RaiseFaults and copy headers with the following directive:

```
   <Copy source="response">  <!-- source is optional.. default is message -->
      <Headers />
   </Copy>
```

The name of the policy might not seem intuitive, however it can serve for the purpose of sending a 302 including and including headers. Find a bundle example [here](https://github.com/dzuluaga/apigee-tutorials/blob/master/apiproxies/forecastweather-faultrule-headers/apiproxy/policies/RaiseFault.fault_always.xml#L3).